# My python GUI-tkinter logo is not changing. I tried all of the methods. It continuously showing (couldn't open "logo.png": no such file or directory)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

windows = Tk()
windows.title("My Project")
windows.geometry('600x400')

icon  = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
windows.iconphoto(True,icon)

# windows.iconbitmap('mylogo.ico')

windows.mainloop()
```

**Error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\PROGRAMMING\Code in VS code\CODES\PROJECT GUI\gui_project.py", line 6, in <module>
    icon  = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4038, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "logo.png": no such file or directory
```

[Here image also added in gui 's folder . I tried direct path also and ico logo too. But failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrW8D.png)

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. There is no 'logo.png' in the current working directory. Are you aware that the current working directory may not be the same as the directory where your .py file is?

Comment: Try to print out the *current working directory* by adding `print(os.getcwd())` (of course you need to add `import os` as well) after importing modules to see whether the current working directory is the directory where the image is.

Comment: @BryanOakley i checked and added perfectly. btw thanks ,

Answer (score 2):

These problems usually occur when you have opened the terminal in the parent directory and the image is inside a child directory. A quick fix would be to take the relative path of the image file and replace it in your code.

This problem can occur again if the terminal is opened in another location as opposed to the directory which contains source code.

For example: Consider the following directory structure

> my_source_code > mypythonscript.py

> my_source_code > images > logo.png

If you try to open a terminal in the "my_source_code" folder and run the .py file, it will not run as the required path is

> "images/logo.png"

Comment: but i tried manually by giving the path of the image. also the error was same.

Comment: The problem is not in the path but in the location in which terminal is opened and the location in which the image files are stored. Share your directory structure; so that we can get a better look at it and help you out!